# spread operator not working in react native

Tags: react-native, dictionary, object, ecmascript-6, concatenation

'browsed' is an array of objects with data for each letter:

```
[
    {
        allowMultiSign: undefined,
        allowSingleSign: "1",
        assignmentStatus: "Browsed",
        disclaimer: null,
        form16: false,
        letterDate: "06-Mar-2020",
        title: "letter02",
        safetyLetterId: 987
    },
    {
        allowMultiSign: undefined,
        allowSingleSign: "1",
        assignmentStatus: "Browsed",
        disclaimer: null,
        form16: false,
        letterDate: "06-Mar-2020",
        title: "letter01",
        safetyLetterId: 123
    },
    {
        allowMultiSign: undefined,
        allowSingleSign: "1",
        assignmentStatus: "Browsed",
        disclaimer: null,
        form16: false,
        letterDate: "06-Mar-2020",
        title: "letter03",
        safetyLetterId: 456
    },
    {
        allowMultiSign: undefined,
        allowSingleSign: "1",
        assignmentStatus: "Browsed",
        disclaimer: null,
        form16: false,
        letterDate: "06-Mar-2020",
        title: "letter04",
        safetyLetterId: 789
    }
]
```

I want to:

1. filter this array for letters that are form16 false and multisign true
2. create an object for each letter that passes the filter that will contain the letter id and title only
3. concat each object inside an object called multisign

1 and 2 are working just fine (I've logged each step). The problem is with #3

when I log the final result -- multisign, I see only the last object. I'm expecting to see all 4 objects inside multisign.

I've used the spread operator before for this same exact task. I'm wondering if I'm just missing a small detail or if it's a compatibility issue. I am using javascript 6.9.0.

```
            let multisign = {};
            browsed.forEach(letter => {
                if (letter.form16 == false && letter.allowMultiSign != false) {
                    let idAndTitle = {
                        safetyLetterId: letter.safetyLetterId,
                        title: letter.title
                    }
                    multisign = { ...multisign, ...idAndTitle }
                }
            });

            console.log(multisign);
        }
```

sample output

```
{
    {
        safetyLetterId: 789,
        title: "letter04"
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share your variable browsed so that we can chek

Comment: Hi, I dont really understand what you are trying to achieve. you have declared let multisign on top and then in the foreach loop you are trying to spread the same multisign variable and assign it to multisign again.

Comment: Can you print sample output, your question is not really clear. Also, there is no **safetyLetterId** in the browsed variable.

Comment: @Ayush sorry, I took out the id for security; I'll add a fake one. what else is not clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because when you spread an object with the same keys they get overridden see: `multisign = { ...multisign, ...idAndTitle }`

That's why the you only get the last one.

My suggestion would be either make multisign an array and push the objects into it or you have to transform the keys for `idAndTitle` every object (maybe affix some index)

EDIT:

If you want to change the keys you have to change the `idAndTitle` object

```js
browsed.forEach((letter, index) => {
                if (letter.form16 == false && letter.allowMultiSign != false) {
                   let idAndTitle = {
                        [`safetyLetterId${index}`]: letter.safetyLetterId,
                        [`title${index}`]: letter.title
                    }
...
```

Now the multisign object should look like this

```
{
  {
    safetyLetterId0: '...'
    title0: '...'
  },
  {
    safetyLetterId1: '...'
    title1: '...'
  },
  ...
}
```

And as you can see this kinda gets ugly so I would suggest to replace multisign with an array and push the new obj to it

Answer (score -1):

I am not really sure what you are trying to achieve and it seems you have less experience with javascript.

but after looking at the code what I feel is that you are trying to filter the letter objects who have form16 as false and allowMultiSign as true. if that is the case, try the below:

```
            let multisign = [];
            browsed.forEach(letter => {
                if (letter.form16 == false && letter.allowMultiSign != false) {
                    let idAndTitle = {
                        safetyLetterId: letter.safetyLetterId,
                        title: letter.title
                    }
                    multisign.push(idAndTitle);
                }
            });

            console.log(multisign);
```

Comment: It is possible to use an array instead of an object for `multisign`, however, that does not answer my question about why the spread operator is not working as expected. Can you back up your assumption that I have 'less experience with javascript' because I'm using an object instead of an array???

Comment: @cDub, Yes, exactly. Leonardo's answer and suggestion backs it up.